# Why Am I getting Token Comma Expected in an If then else power query statement

Tags: dax, powerquery

I have this statement and according to all I've seen there shouldn't be a comma anywhere in the statement but for some reason I keep getting Token Comma Expected error and if I put a comma it raises other errors:

= if [Fiscal Month Year] = "2021-06" then CALCULATE(SUM([Beg. Inventory CS]+CALCULATE(SUM([SAP Plan CS])-CALCULATE(SUM([Forecast CS])))) else  CALCULATE(SUM([SAP Plan CS])-CALCULATE(SUM([Forecast CS])))

Comment: it looks like you are mixing DAX and M. DAX IF fuction doesn't use THEN and ELSE but commas instead. https://dax.guide/if/

Comment: I replaced then and else with commas but the error says I need then and else. I used if [Fiscal Month Year] = 2021-06 then SUM([Beg. Inventory CS]+SUM([SAP Plan CS])-[Forecast CS]) else SUM([SAP Plan CS])-[Forecast CS] and got no syntax error but then I get SUM is not recognized

Comment: it looks like you are writing a query in Power Query. Then the language involved is M and not DAX

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is a difference between If and if, if you use "if" then you will need to use then/else, but if you use "If" it works as in Excel. Ex. If(logical validation, true, false)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).